# streaming a video retrieved from google using drive api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-drive-api

i know i can get fileinfo in node.js using

```
const driveService = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
const response = await driveService.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media',
  fields: 'webViewLink'
});
```

but i don't understand what part of the information i need send back to my (react) client in order to be able to stream the video(without the client being logged in) and how to actually stream it. Can anybody help me here? I can't find a tutorial for that anywhere